# Why did sed stop working with emoji overnight, but only on 1 of 3 machines?

Tags: cygwin, sed, emoji

I have 3 machine all running the same version of sed (cygwin), under TCC command line.

This morning, I woke up to sed failing to work with emoji, but only on 1 of the 3 machines.

The sed version is the same on all 3 machines, and the TCC command line version is 28 on one of the working machines, 31 on another, and 31 on the broken machine.

In other words, the error is not version-specific.

```
C:\>echo gOlIaTh | sed -e 's/goliath/GOLIATH/gi'
GOLIATH

C:\>echo gOlIaTh | sed -e 's/goliath/GOLIATH/gi'
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

I have no clue how this is happening, why it cropped up overnight when I'm not changing things while sleeping, why it's only happening on 1 computer with the v31 command line. I don't know why any of this is happening and it's frustrating.

Comment: Is this happening also from the Cygwin Terminal ? As you are calling SED from CMD it is likely an issue from Windows side .

Comment: Smells like a problem with your _locale_. Could it be that the `LANG` setting is now different to what it was before?